# minumum intra-day profit in equity

Tags: pine-script

As you know we can limit the max. daily loss  with function of `strategy.risk.max_intraday_loss(value=maxPercLoss, type=strategy.percent_of_equity)` .

How can I do this if I want to limit the daily profit instead of the loss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks alot Bjorgum, from TV Discord channel

```
strategy_risk_max_intraday_gain_percent(perc) =>
var zero = 0.0
percProfit = strategy.netprofit / strategy.initial_capital*100
zero := ta.change(time("D")) ? percProfit : zero
result = not (percProfit - zero > perc)
```

long = longCondition and strategy_risk_max_intraday_gain_percent(2)